# Max-height transition when adding class

Tags: css

I'm trying to do a transition for max-height when adding a class. The backwards transition works just fine. But the expanding transition doesn't.

Here the code:

```
.max-height-animation {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

.max-height-animation.full-animation {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

Adding / removing the class depending on `toggle`:

```
<textarea class="max-height-animation" :class="{ 'full-animation': toggle }">
</textarea>
```

Comment: The code itself works fine, if you apply it to something like a `div` - https://jsfiddle.net/hyk82mj4/ (larger duration here, so that the effect is more noticeable.) Applying this to a `textarea` though appears to be more problematic - because that will not automatically get a height that corresponds to its content; in lack of an actual height _specified_ via CSS, it will fall back on the `rows` of the textarea (which defaults to `2`, if not specified.)

Comment: All right, thanks. That explains a lot.Guess I either need to use JS or scaleY.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you're setting the max-height property directly in the class for the expanded state, which overrides the transition you've defined. This means that the browser will immediately set the max-height to 1000px without applying the transition animation.

To fix this, you need to define the max-height property in the base class and only modify it within the transition rules. Here's the corrected CSS:

```css
.max-height-animation {
  /* Set the initial max-height */
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Define the transition */
  transition: max-height 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
}

/* Define the expanded state using a pseudo-class */
.max-height-animation:not(.full-animation) {
  max-height: 0;
}

/* Add the fully expanded style within the transition */
.max-height-animation.full-animation {
  /* Set the max-height directly */
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

This approach ensures that the transition starts from the initial max-height of 0 and gradually grows to 1000px, creating a smooth animation.

Comment: It sadly still jumps right to the full height instead of growing.

Comment: _"which overrides the transition you've defined"_ - no, it doesn't. The value of the `transition` property does not change at all, due to that second additional class.

Comment: @CBroe Any idea from your side why the transition ain't working in the growing direction?